# I get this error while installing mysql

Tags: dpkg, mysql, dependencies

When I try to install MySQL on my Ubuntu I get the below error in the terminal.

```
nuwan@nuwan-Aspire-5740:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libevent-core-2.0-5 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common
  mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libevent-core-2.0-5 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 18.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 161 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libevent-core-2.0-5 amd64 2.0.21-stable-2 [69.4 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-common all 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [15.1 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [6,325 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-5.7 amd64 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [1,762 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [7,728 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-5.7 amd64 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [2,856 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-server all 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [10.1 kB]
Fetched 18.8 MB in 41min 57s (7,454 B/s)                                       
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64.
(Reading database ... 391095 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libevent-core-2.0-5_2.0.21-stable-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.7_5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.7.
(Reading database ... 391257 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu16) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Setting up libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-2) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu16) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Below is the last lines I get when run `journalctl -xe`

```
lines 1242-1264/1264 (END)
පෙබ 19 10:18:41 nuwan-Aspire-5740 sudo[3383]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
පෙබ 19 10:18:41 nuwan-Aspire-5740 sudo[3383]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
පෙබ 19 10:18:56 nuwan-Aspire-5740 dhclient[3369]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s29u1u2c4i2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x155e2d64)
පෙබ 19 10:19:07 nuwan-Aspire-5740 NetworkManager[1161]: <warn>  [1487479747.3647] dhcp4 (enp0s29u1u2c4i2): request timed out
පෙබ 19 10:19:07 nuwan-Aspire-5740 NetworkManager[1161]: <info>  [1487479747.3647] dhcp4 (enp0s29u1u2c4i2): state changed unknown -> timeout
පෙබ 19 10:19:07 nuwan-Aspire-5740 NetworkManager[1161]: <info>  [1487479747.3810] dhcp4 (enp0s29u1u2c4i2): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 3369
පෙබ 19 10:19:07 nuwan-Aspire-5740 NetworkManager[1161]: <info>  [1487479747.3810] dhcp4 (enp0s29u1u2c4i2): state changed timeout -> done
පෙබ 19 10:19:07 nuwan-Aspire-5740 NetworkManager[1161]: <info>  [1487479747.3815] device (enp0s29u1u2c4i2): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-un
පෙබ 19 10:19:07 nuwan-Aspire-5740 NetworkManager[1161]: <warn>  [1487479747.3823] device (enp0s29u1u2c4i2): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 2'
පෙබ 19 10:19:07 nuwan-Aspire-5740 NetworkManager[1161]: <info>  [1487479747.3837] device (enp0s29u1u2c4i2): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [1
පෙබ 19 10:19:07 nuwan-Aspire-5740 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s29u1u2c4i2: link is not ready
පෙබ 19 10:19:07 nuwan-Aspire-5740 NetworkManager[1161]: <info>  [1487479747.3922] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 2'
පෙබ 19 10:19:07 nuwan-Aspire-5740 NetworkManager[1161]: <info>  [1487479747.3942] device (enp0s29u1u2c4i2): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 2' (0
පෙබ 19 10:19:07 nuwan-Aspire-5740 NetworkManager[1161]: <info>  [1487479747.3945] device (enp0s29u1u2c4i2): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [
පෙබ 19 10:19:07 nuwan-Aspire-5740 NetworkManager[1161]: <info>  [1487479747.3953] device (enp0s29u1u2c4i2): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 
පෙබ 19 10:19:07 nuwan-Aspire-5740 NetworkManager[1161]: <info>  [1487479747.3958] device (enp0s29u1u2c4i2): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 7
පෙබ 19 10:19:07 nuwan-Aspire-5740 NetworkManager[1161]: <info>  [1487479747.3964] dhcp4 (enp0s29u1u2c4i2): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds
පෙබ 19 10:19:07 nuwan-Aspire-5740 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s29u1u2c4i2: link is not ready
පෙබ 19 10:19:07 nuwan-Aspire-5740 NetworkManager[1161]: <info>  [1487479747.3992] dhcp4 (enp0s29u1u2c4i2): dhclient started with pid 3389
පෙබ 19 10:19:07 nuwan-Aspire-5740 dhclient[3389]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s29u1u2c4i2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xbae6ff49)
පෙබ 19 10:19:10 nuwan-Aspire-5740 dhclient[3389]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s29u1u2c4i2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0xbae6ff49)
පෙබ 19 10:19:16 nuwan-Aspire-5740 dhclient[3389]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s29u1u2c4i2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0xbae6ff49)
පෙබ 19 10:19:25 nuwan-Aspire-5740 dhclient[3389]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s29u1u2c4i2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0xbae6ff49)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: What is the command you used to install mysql?  Also will you give the output (at least the last 10 or 15 lines of `journalctl -xe`.   First run the install command, append the copy/paste output of `journalctl -xe` to your question.

Comment: @L.D.James Done

Comment: You ran `journalctl -xe`.  Was it immediately after running the the command to install mysql?  ...before running any other commands?  The output doesn't appear that way.  Also what was the command you run to install mysql?

Comment: @L.D.James first question - no, not immediately after.. Second question -  sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Comment: You'll have to run the install command.  Then immediately after run `journalctl -xe`.  The messages associated with the mysql install command has scrolled off.  The log will show the most recent information about the system.  It's continuously being updated.  Once you run the install command again, replace the log that you have now with the new one.

Comment: @L.D.James should I purge mysql now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53885/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-nuwan-thisara).